# Функция не изменяет элементы списка

Tags: python

```
def make_great(magicans):
    for magican in magicans:
        magican = "the Great " + magican

def show_magicans(magicans):
    for magican in magicans:
        print(magican)


magicans = ['valery', 'alice']
make_great(magicans)
show_magicans(magicans)
```

Есть список имен. Функция ' make_great() ' должна модифицировать каждое имя. На выходе список остается преждним.

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

Comment: Можно, `for i, magican in enumerate(magicans): magicans[i] = "the Great " + magican`

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное! последний вопрос: так как я писал - меняется только копия magican, верно? при этом никуда не сохраняясь

Comment: Можно сказать, что в python переменные представляют собой ссылки на значения, поэтому изменение переменной в цикле является всего лишь изменением ссылки. То есть раньше ссылка указывала на строку `'valery'`, а теперь указывает на строку `'the Great valery'`

Comment: еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так:

```
def make_great(magicans):
    magicans[:] = ['the Great {}'.format(x) for x in magicans]
```

Пример:

```
In [174]: l = ['A','B','C']

In [175]: make_great(l)

In [176]: l
Out[176]: ['the Great A', 'the Great B', 'the Great C']
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @ВалерийМихеенко, [string.format() - форматирование строк](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: Думаю, более ценным ответом на данный вопрос было бы объяснение, почему код автора не работает (но самому мне писать лень))

Comment: @andreymal Вы можете ответить ссылкой! Буду очень признателен!

Comment: @ВалерийМихеенко, вот похожие вопросы в английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081217/how-to-modify-list-entries-during-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотели только "напечатать" строку + имя из списка, то можно поместить print в функцию, где формируется этот объект.

```
def make_great(magicans):
    for magican in magicans:
        magican = "the Great " + magican
        print(magican)
```

Иначе вам необходимо задать новую переменную, в которую поместить результат сложения строк и вернуть эту переменную в функции (далее этот результат можно будет напечатать).

```
def make_great(magicans):
    result = []
    for magican in magicans:
        magican = "the Great " + magican
        result.append(magican)
    return result

def show_magicans(magicans):
    for magican in magicans:
        print(magican)

show_magicans(make_great(magicans))
```

Comment: уже разобрался с этим, но все равно спасибо!